# Workflow Manager 1.0 move to another server

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow-manager

Any feedback on this issue is greatly appreciated. We are in the process of scaling down a farm and need to move Workflow Manager 1.0 from Server B to Server A.

My initial thought was to  try and join Server A to the farm, thus receiving the correct configuration settings, making in primary and then drop Server B. No such luck however. Does anyone know how to go about doing this in a safe and secure manner?

Thanks!

EDIT: When trying to join one server to the managementDB, we receive: "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'CertificateAutoGenerationKey'. The certificate generation key does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length and password complexity requirements."

Which is odd since WFM is already running on the other machine?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Past i was able to move the WFM from one server to other.

- Install the WFM and CU on the new farm.
- Run the WFM wizard join the server to existing farm
- Now move to 1st server and disjoin it from Farm.
- Now i reran the `Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite https://samesitecolelction" -WorkflowHostUri "https://newservernam:12290"`with new endpoints.

Now test your workflows

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Workflow topology supports either 3 or 1 servers, so if you need to reduce Farm to one Server

1. Make backup of the databases
2. Remove all machines (keep databases)
3. Join existing farm from existing machine

Have a look at this great presentation on Channel 9:
video.ch9.ms/sessions/spc/2014/SPC356_Harbar.pptx

Comment: Hi, it's more about moving WFM from one server to the other, as it is about reducing farm-size though. Would these steps be relevant for that as well (moving)? Thanks!

Comment: Which farm are you reducing? SharePoint farm? Do you have WF on separate server or on one of the SharePoint ones?

Comment: We're reducing an SP13-farm (APP+WFE) down to just one shared instance. WF is installed on the WFE (bad practice, I know..) and will be moved to APP.

Comment: When trying to join one server to the managementDB, we receive: "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'CertificateAutoGenerationKey'. The certificate generation key does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length and password complexity requirements."

Which is odd since WFM is already running on the other machine?!